# SQL C# trying to access top 10 values

Tags: c#, sql

So I'm ordering different ids by average rating doing the following:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 10 MovieID, ROUND(AVG(CAST(Rating AS Float)), 2) as AvgRating " + 
      "FROM Reviews GROUP BY MovieID ORDER BY AvgRating DESC;";
dbCmd = new SqlCommand();
dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
SqlDataReader result = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();
int movieId = -1;
while (result.Read())
{
    movieId = result.GetInt32(0);
    break;
}
```

The sql query is supposed to retrieve the top 10 ids. I can get the first one using `result.GetInt32(0)`, but I'm wondering how I get the rest, because if I try `result.GetInt32(1)` it goes out of bounds on the array.

Any insight would be helpful

Comment: I think you will always use getInt32(0) because it's the first column you want, but you're only collecting one movieID? Why aren't you making an array of IDs or anything?

Comment: I'm not using an array because I don't know how to collect the rest of the ids in the array.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `while (...) { break; }`

Comment: @ManPerson fair enough, hopefully I (or someone else who comes along) can help you figure that out. What you have is not far from what you need. I think ta brings up a good point, too. You don't want to break from your while loop, you want to continue until you are done, so take that line out.

Comment: You don't understand how `DataReaders` work. You are returning 10 rows of 1 column each. `GetInt(0)` references the array of columns, basically`GetInt(columnIndex)`, therefore anything greater than 0 will be out of bounds if you only have one colum. Inside the while loop `result` represents a row of data. Don't `break` the loop and collect the data in an array or what ever you wnat to do with it. Please read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Actaully re-reading the question you have two columns, ID and AvgRating, I'm surprised `getInt32(1)` didn't work. I would expect `getInt32(>1)` to error. Alos consider DatAdapters and DataSets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need here is to make an array of movieIds, because you are planning on reading 10 different movies, right? Why don't you change it to something like this:

```
int[] movies = new int[10];
int cntr = 0;
while(result.Read())
{
   movies[cntr] = result.GetInt32(0);
   cntr++;
}
```

**EDIT**

Of course, this is not error proof. What do you do if you don't have enough data for 10 movies, your array might only be populated partially, so remember to protect against something like that.

**EDIT 2**

For a better explanation, and I'm sorry I've left this out, the reason you should use a while loop (which I suspect you understand, because you put it in already) is so you can iterate over your result set. Sure, you've requested 10 rows, but it's not guaranteed that you receive 10, so you should use while instead of a for loop. Also, I added a counter variable that is used to see which value you are at, and puts the id in the corresponding spot in the array.

I do see two major potential errors here, that you will have to decide how to handle.
1) If less than 10 rows are returned, how will you handle the null values in the array?
2) If more than 10 rows are returned, how will you prevent attempting to give a movie id at `movies[11]`? I recommend doing something like this, too:

```
while(result.Read() && cntr < 10)
```

Comment: There really should be an `EDIT 3` here that explains what `using` it.

Comment: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` yet they are not `Dispose`'d. `using` will do this automatically.

Comment: Sure but the scope of my answer doesn't go out that far and neither does OP's question. How do we know they don't have a `using` block already?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with following

> result.GetInt32(0);

By using it you compromise on code readability instead of that use

```
int MovieID= Convert.ToInt32(result["MovieID"]);
```

Now you can add it in any list/array.

```
int[] movieIDs = new int[10];
int counter = 0;

while(result.Read())
{
 movieIDs [counter] = Convert.ToInt32(result["MovieID"]);
 counter++;
}
```

OR

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>();

while(result.Read())
{
 int movieID  = Convert.ToInt32(result["MovieID"]);
 list.Add(movieID);
}
```

Advantages of list would be

- you do not need to keep count of index like counter
- If tomorrow you wish to return 20 IDs then list can handle it
- And all other benefits like sort,arrange etc. will be there with built in methods

Comment: Oops was going to suggest list but you already answered it so im just gonna upvote this instead :)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `result["movieid"]` syntax. I was going to mention that but could not for the life of me remember how it was done or pull up any source code.